# Queue datastruct -- find first element in queue that has not previously been queued

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler. When it visits a page, it pulls all the links on that page (that satisfy conditions, blah blah) and adds them to the queue of pages to visit. I don't want the crawler to visit the same page twice. My current solution is clunky: when a page is visited, I add the URL to a list of visited pages (so moves from queue to list). Then, when I go to visit a next page, I recursively 'pop' off links from the queue until I get one that is not in the list of previously visited pages. Like I said, this seems clunky and inefficient and there must be a better way.

Here's my code for returning the first unvisited page from a queue:

```
def first_new_page(queue, visited): 
    ''' 
    Given a queue and list of visited pages, returns the first unvisited URL in the queue 
    '''
    if queue.empty(): 
        return -1 
    rv = queue.get()
    if rv not in visited: 
        return rv 
    else: 
        return first_new_page(queue, visited)
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using `scrapy`, the best-of-breed framework for Python web crawlers these days?

Comment: Eh, no good reason. In hindsight, yeah I probably should have. At this point, I think I'll stick with my current set up and try to make it better (it works now, just looking for ways to optimize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **set()**.

#### updated

OK before that I wasn't really giving you a solution but the technique of how you should use **set()** than poping your list, for the sake of completeness this is what you're after:

```
visited = set()

queue = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.microsfot.com']

def crawl_the_page(link):
    # ...crawling...
    visited.add(link)
    return


# you just for through the queue list
# no need to pop the list, use the set() to compare instead
for url in queue:
    if url not in visited:
        #... do your stuff ...
        #... crawl your pages ...
        crawl_the_page(url)
```

Comment: They say "microsfot" is going to be the next big company :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The main downside to this is that sets do not preserve order, and I would like to visit the sites in the order that I add them to the queue.

Comment: @Craig, the list of **urls** is IN ORDER. you just need to check if the url (in order) you're going to visit is/isn't in your **set()**... and **do your stuff**... do you get what I mean?

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Ok, the new main downside is that this will be inefficient in my case -- each page I'm visiting has about 60 links and there is a lot of repeats between pages. In your solution, I have to check every link on the pages against the visited before adding it to the queue. In practice, I'm going to add a max number visited, such that even though my queue explodes to thousands of links (with repeats) I only need to go down a couple hundred. I'll give your answer the check mark for now unless someone comes up with a better one :)

Comment: I also could just be misunderstanding your answer, so feel free to shoot me down if I'm just missing something!

Comment: @Craig, I wasn't showing you the solution, it's just the technique you require to achieve what you wanted, let me update my answer to be a little more understandable

Comment: I understand that -- but the issue (which, to be fair, I never specified as a constraint in my question) is that I don't want to check every URL I come across against the visited URLs before adding it to the queue.

Comment: @Craig, I do understand, and that's what you don't need to do, you can simply just add those urls in the queue, and only PROCEED to the page if the url is not in the **set()**, **set()** is very efficient in key lookup.

Comment: Ok, great -- that's what I'm going with. Thanks for your patience and great answers!

Comment: @Craig, no worries mate, we've all been there ;)